# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol textView

Tags: android, textview

I'm **completely** new to Android Studio.

I have just installed it on Windows 10 and since I wanted to learn how to use it, I have started to follow the online guide (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#Up).

I am literally following it step by step, but when it comes to this part of the code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
```

the "textView" part after "findViewById" appears red and I get this error message: "**cannot resolve symbol 'textView'**".

This happens even if I have imported **android.widget.TextView**.

Maybe this is  stupid question, but I am completely new to Android Studio.
Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Can you add the contents of `activity_display_message.xml` to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your file R.layout.activity_display_message, the `<TextView>` tag must have `android:id="@+id/textView"`

Can you include your XML File?

Comment: Oh thank you! 

In the xml file there was written android:id="@+id/textView4" while in the java file there was only textView!

Now it doens't give this error anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by buutqn

> `<TextView>` tag must have `android:id="@+id/textView"`

This is in the file: app.res.layout.activity_display_message.xml 
under the Text tab(as opposed to Design tab).

This issue can be duplicated by deleting the TextView box from the design tab, and inserting a new (second) text view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was for other reason although the error was the same. I copied the following code out of the *OnCreate* method.

```
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
```

The text *(TextView)* before *findViewById* was not neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

The TextView object of the Activity_display_message is called TextView2, instead of Textview. So I tried and changed:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

for

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Erase the statement, then retype it. There is going to be a small pop up indicating you to press a command. It is basically an import library issue when you press the command (for macOS it is <kbd>⌥⏎</kbd> ) the respective library will be added. If this does not work, close Android Studio and reopen it . I am not an expert on this matter, but this worked for me hence I am sharing.

Answer (score 0):

After tiresome searches and updating settings,
I Just clicked Invalidate Catches -> Invalidate And Restart
And Done! TextView Error Disappeared[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QebLq.png)